# Error in loading the page icon

Tags: html, header, favicon

I tried to add my icon
but not loading

```
<head>
<title>M-Quran</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" lang="ar" />
<meta http-equiv="default-style" content="default-style"/>
<meta name="author" content="Ahmed Mohsen" />
<meta name="description" content="feel free to listen Quran with most reciters" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Quran , Islamic" />
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link type="text/css" href="homeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="homeJS.js"></script>
</head>
```

so , what's the problem ?

Comment: Did you try to open this icon by URL in the browser's address bar?

Comment: Yes , it opens without problems

Comment: Browser, sometimes, caches the icon and do not update it as soon as it changes. Clear browser's cache or try from another browser.

Comment: what if i placed this tag in a wrong place in the header tag
or , it doesn't make difference

Comment: It makes the difference, but some browsers request favicon by themselves.

Comment: More than likely your path is wrong.

Comment: @AhmedMohsen location of the tag is correct. Except, may be, that if the page is in the folder - request for .ico leads to the same folder, not to the server's root. You can also check that your html code is correct at http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the favicon.ico from your web browser? Also I recommend you use the full url to your favicon.ico. Something like this:

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://yourWebsite.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://yourWebsite.com/favicon.ico" />
```

and make sure you can access your favicon from the url: `http://yourWebsite.com/favicon.ico`

Comment: the Icon in the same folder

Comment: @AhmedMohsen Did you try using the full url?

Comment: <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="file:///C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/M-Quran/favicon.ico" />
yes

Comment: @AhmedMohsen this is not a full url.. this 'url' is available only to and from you computer